# How to copy indices from one mesh to another ? (vertex numbers/index/id) (the same uv)

Tags: vertices, linked-data

I have two objects with the same number of vertices. I dont know how, but one object got its vertex numbers  changed (indices) As you see on the picture numbers on one are diferent than on the other. Is there a way to transfer these numbers to another mesh so they both could be the same? I have the same working UV ready for both meshes, will it help somehow to establish the numbers ? [image]

Comment: Not sure if this helps you but you can sort the vertices with *[Mesh > Sort Elements ...](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/sort_elements.html)*. If you sort the vertices of both objects in the same way the order should be the same.

Comment: Thank you for tip!  I just tried those options that You mentiond, somehow non of those made numbers in boath meshes the same...  it sounds like it should at least make both meshes sheare the same numbers in the same places, somehow it doesnt. Or is it me doing something wrong?( i selected sorting elements while both meshes were selected)

Comment: Oh yes, I see. The problem is the sort order criteria (cursor distance, axis, etc) and the fact that the meshes are similar but not the same. This varies the distance to the cursor, for example, and results in a different order. Unfortunately, shape keys rely on the indices. You can't make the meshes have the same shape this way.